# How to play a video inside an iframe using selenium with node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, iframe

I'm trying to play a video inside an `<iframe>` using selenium with node.js. I have tried

```
`driver.sleep("2000");
await driver.switchTo().frame(0);
let playVideo = By.id("shakaVid");
// await driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(playVideo));
await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(playVideo), 15*1000);
await driver.findElement(playVideo).play();`
```

I'm getting `TimeoutError: Waiting for element to be located By(css selector, *[id="shakaVid"])` I have also tried `By.css("iframe html > body > video")` but none of these are working. And I don't know how to test that selenium is shifting its focus to iframe. So, I have tried multiple things.

This is how my html is :
[image: Elements]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that's not the first frame, try giving web element for iframe instead of indexing:

```
let iframe = By.cssSelector("iframe[name^='vdoFrame'][src*='playerAssets']");
await driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(iframe));
```

if this css selector `iframe[id^='vdoFrame'][src*='playerAssets']` is locating the right iframe (Please verify that in element section when we inspect), then you should be able to switch to iframe and rest of your code should work just fine.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I check iframe corresponding to `iframe[id^='vdoFrame'][src*='playerAssets']` after opening elements?

Comment: Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `css selector` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Comment: Also, Can you please explain what does the code means? P.s: I tried finding there is only one iframe.

Comment: You were looking for the iframe based on index which is not a stable way, so I have suggested to use iframe web element instead of index.

Comment: I tried pasting the code. I'm getting 0/0.

Comment: selenium is throwing `NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"iframe[id^='vdoFrame'][src*='playerAssets']"}`

Comment: No it should not be 0/0, it should be 1/1, can you share that HTML in text format or link to the page ?

Comment: My bad it should have been `iframe[name^='vdoFrame'][src*='playerAssets']`,  I was using id instead of name, Please try with the mention CSS selector.

Comment: Yes. Now It located the iframe. Let me run the entire code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240799/discussion-between-era-sq-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: Was this resolved? or are you still looking for some assistance? if so, can you share credentials to my email id? I can have a look.

Comment: Send you credentials in the discussion.

Comment: @eras'q: Looked into it, have left few locators in chat. Let me know how it goes !